# How to Access my NAS Server from another Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

I need some help with my network, I think the solution is pretty simple, but it is very difficult to find good answers out there.

How can I access my NAS server with Computer 2. 
When I am connected to Router 1, I have no issues to establish a connection to my NAS because we are in the same local Network. 
Router 1 and Router 2 are directly connected with a LAN cable.

Which configuration I need to change in the routers so I have a big local network, so I can connect to my NAS.

Thank you very much.

[NAS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4aJ.png)

Comment: It appears that your routers have set up two subnets which is why you can connect from Computer 1 on one router but not the other. Connect the two routers LAN port to LAN port and ensure they are on the same network subnet.

Comment: ... And make sure that they don't share IP addresses and that only one of them is acting as a DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess a bit at your network, but you can do the following and it will work.

Pick one router as your main router connected to your ISP modem. Call this Router 1.

1. Connect a LAN port on Router 2 to a LAN port on Router 1.
2. Go to the Configuration page of Router 2, give the LAN a static IP address on your Network (so it will not get lost in a restart)
3. Turn DHCP OFF on Router 2.

Now you have one big network all on one subnet which is what you want. This works very well for me.

Comment: FYI doesn't work for some models, just wasted 3-4 hours trying different things - d-link dwr921 is a curse. It should work, but it doesn't. (either that or my funbox, but considering the static IP set to the Router 2 (d-link) gets reset everytime to 10.0.0.1 speaks for itself)

Comment: What I suggested works great for decent quality routers.

Comment: Sure! Just commenting so someone doesnt waste time figuring out if it's user error or it's possible their router doesn't support it, not everyone browsing superuser has access to decent quality routers.

Comment: Alternative step 2: create a static lease for Router 2 on DHCP settings on Router 1.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the network map I think there is no need for a second router. Router2 should be switched to Access Point mode, so laptop2 can connect to the network in that area. But there is no need for routing there.